Spring boot cloud config server can't find config files located in google cloud storage bucket
I am working on deploying some spring boot applications with google cloud build and run.  I would like to set up a spring boot cloud config server that pulls the config files for each of my microservices from a google cloud storage bucket.  I am able to get the config server app up and running in google cloud, but whenever I try to access config files for their given microservice, the config server is unable to find them.  My config server application.yml looks like this:
spring:
  application:
    name: myapp-cloud-config-server
  profiles:
    active: native
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        native:
          search-locations:
            - gs://myapp-config/myapp-api-gateway/
            - gs://myapp-config/myapp-auth-api/

My google cloud storage bucket is named myapp-config, and it contains two folders, one for each of the search locations in the yml file above.  Each of these folders contains a yml file for their respective microservice, for example, myapp-api-gateway.yml.
Some things to note, the config server app is running in google cloud and has access to the bucket (Storage Admin Role).  I have checked whether the yml files in the bucket are accessible via gsutil, and I am able to pull them.  It seems like I am missing something so simple but can't figure it out.  If any additional resources may be helpful, I can edit the post to add them.
